# I can't seem to check a value in a particular column of a datatable. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datatable, datacolumn

I have a datatable with data in it (customer addresses).  In some instances, column ADDR3 doesn't have a value and column ADDR2 does.  I'm attempting to check the value of ADDR3 and if it doesn't contain a value I want to copy the value in ADDR2 to ADDR3 and then blank out ADDR2.  I was trying to use the below code, but it isn't working.  I placed a breakpoint after my 'if' statement, but the program never breaks.  But, I know for a fact that a lot of the rows have null ADDR3 fields.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
            foreach (DataRow row in dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows)
            {
                object value = row["ADDR3"];
                if (value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    row["ADDR3"] = row["ADDR2"];
                    row["ADDR2"] = " ";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you place a breakpoint *on* your if statement and see if `value` is DBNull?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that.  It's just that I have a few hundred rows to go through before I get to the data that has a null value in ADDR3.  But, if that's my only recourse, then I'll do it.  But, as far as my code goes, should it work?  Could it be a case where it isn't null but some other value like " "?

Comment: Right-click on your breakpoint, click on Filter... and choose the value before your null value to prevent going through your hundreds rows

Comment: Oliver, that is an awesome tip.  I had no idea I could do that.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your `row["ADDR3"]` value is NEVER equal to `DbNull.Value`. This is often the case with data tables that were transferred over a web service, for example (there will be empty strings instead of nulls due to the XML transformations).

Put a break point BEFORE your `if` and find exactly what the value is. You might try checking for `row["ADDR3"] == null` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["ADDR3"].ToString())`

Comment: That did it!  It was whitespace, not null.  Thanks so much!  As soon as the timer is up, I'll mark the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the value to null (rather than DBNull.Value)? I believe DBNull.Value is exclusive for certain database objects and does not appear once read into a dataset/datatable.

Comment: I'll try it and see what happens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows)
{
    if (
        row.IsNull("ADDR3") // True if the value is null
        ||
        String.IsNullOrWhitespace(row["ADDR3"]) // True if the value is "", " ", etc.
       )
    {
        row["ADDR3"] = row["ADDR2"];
        row["ADDR2"] = " ";
    }
}
```